My mat-form-field doesn't work unless it has a ngIf attribute even though it's redundant
I've been tasked to migrate a project that's using Angular v9 to Angular v17 and everything's been smooth so far without having to change much, but I've encountered a really weird bug and I can't find anything on internet that relates to it. Appreciate any help.
For whatever reason my mat-form-field doesn't work unless I put a *ngIf attribute to it. If I omit ngIf altogether, it renders a native html input but doesn't render the styles or anything that material input component should have
If I give you the exact code, it's like this
<mat-form-field class="organization-name" appearance="fill" *ngIf="true">
      <mat-label class="label">Organization Short Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Enter Organization Short Name" 
       formControlName="organizationShortName" />
</mat-form-field>

works, but
<mat-form-field class="organization-name" appearance="fill" >
  <mat-label class="label">Organization Short Name</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Enter Organization Short Name" formControlName="organizationShortName" />
</mat-form-field>

doesn't.
Which is very weird because here *ngIf="true" is an unnecessary always truthy statement.
This is how it renders on screen when I include the *ngIf,

And when I don't include it,

My version of the related packages are,

"@angular/forms": "^17.3.3"
"@angular/material": "^17.3.8"
"@angular/forms": "^17.3.3"
"@angular/core": "^17.3.0"


That sounds strange. Could you try to reproduce it in StackBlitz?


Be sure you import the BrowserAnimations or provideAnimations()

Check if you import
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';

in the module where is declared the component or is you're using
standalone components in the standalone component

Check if you're import the correct .css


I've never heard about this problem
